# ローカルマシンに言語の実行環境を用意せず、エディターで補完を出す方法

Tags: macos, node.js, docker, vscode

**ローカル環境に特定の言語の実行環境をインストールしないで、開発時にはDockerのコンテナを実行環境としてフォルダーをホストからマウントしてソースを実行環境から扱う。**

といったかたちで開発をする場合、ローカル環境ではエディターを使ったコードの補完は諦めるしか無いのでしょうか。
また、補完が出ないことに納得がいかないところがあるので理由をご教示いただきたいです。

例えば

- ローカル環境にはNode.jsをインストールしない
- Node.jsのDockerイメージを使ってNode.jsの実行環境を用意する
- ソースはローカル環境でVisualStudioCodeを使って編集する
- Docker Composeを使ってコンテナは立ち上げる

叶えたいのはここで「VisualStudioCodeのインテリセンスを機能させること」です。

Node.jsの標準モジュールはローカル環境に存在しないため補完の候補に出てこないのだと思いますが、補完を出す方法はありますでしょうか。
また、node_modulesに入っているライブラリまで補完ができないのはなぜでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 中身分かってなくて検索結果の文言だけですが、この辺が参考になるかも。[rcjsuen/dockerfile-language-server-nodejs](https://github.com/rcjsuen/dockerfile-language-server-nodejs), [microsoft/vscode-docker](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docker), [Feature - Start the Language Server as a docker container #212](https://github.com/lingua-pupuli/puppet-vscode/issues/212), [(GH-375) Implement Docker connection handler #450](https://github.com/lingua-pupuli/puppet-vscode/pull/450)

Comment: どのようにDockerを使用されているかわからない(たとえば構成をdocker-compose.ymlなどで追記してもらえれば参考になるかもしれません)のでなんともいえませんが、どっちかというとVSCodeならRemoteを活用するといいのかも。 [Dockerで立ち上げた開発環境をVS Codeで開く! - Qiita](https://qiita.com/yoskeoka/items/01c52c069123e0298660)